# Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

Tags: ssl

I have a Java 8 springboot application raising the following exception when connecting a https server:
Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7

**CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)**
**5.4.54-1.0.0.std7c.el7.2.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 16 10:02:20 CST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**
**jdk1.8.0_202**

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported curve: 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1068)啊
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:300)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
```

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class Ciphers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        String[] defaultCiphers = ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        String[] availableCiphers = ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();

        TreeMap ciphers = new TreeMap();

        for(int i=0; i<availableCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(availableCiphers[i], Boolean.FALSE);

        for(int i=0; i<defaultCiphers.length; ++i )
            ciphers.put(defaultCiphers[i], Boolean.TRUE);

        System.out.println("Default\tCipher");
        for(Iterator i = ciphers.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry cipher=(Map.Entry)i.next();

            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(cipher.getValue()))
                System.out.print('*');
            else
                System.out.print(' ');

            System.out.print('\t');
            System.out.println(cipher.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
Default Cipher
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
*       TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
*       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Who can help me solve

Comment: That OID is P-256 aka prime256v1 or secp256r1, the most widely used X9-type curve, and should definitely work, even in RedHat/CentOS unless ancient (up to 6.something around 2013 they excluded EC crypto, but even on those versions it would be checked before negotiating ECDHE keyexchange and not cause _this_ error). Even if your system has weird crypto, like maybe PKCS11, it should have been caught earlier, as [commented in the code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/jdk8u202-ga/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/HandshakeMessage.java#L1053). Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to have something to do with opentelemetry